# Extract PKCS7 Container memory leak during receipt validation

Tags: swift, pkcs#7, receipt-validation

XCode detected memory leaks in one of my function:
[image]

The func is responsible for extracting PKCS7 container. Here the code of the func:

```
func extractPKCS7Container() throws -> UnsafeMutablePointer<PKCS7> {
    guard let receiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL,
        let certificateURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "AppleIncRootCertificate", withExtension: "cer"),
        let receiptData = NSData(contentsOf: receiptURL),
        let certificateData = NSData(contentsOf: certificateURL) else {
            throw ReceiptError.couldNotFindReceipt
    }
    let bio = BIOWrapper(data: receiptData)
    let p7 = d2i_PKCS7_bio(bio.bio, nil)
    guard p7 != nil else {
        throw ReceiptError.emptyReceiptContents
    }
    OpenSSL_add_all_digests()

    let x509Store = X509StoreWrapper()
    let certificate = X509Wrapper(data: certificateData)
    x509Store.addCert(x509: certificate)
    let payload = BIOWrapper()
    guard PKCS7_verify(p7, nil, x509Store.store, nil, payload.bio, 0) == 1 else {
        throw ReceiptError.receiptNotSigned
    }
    return p7!
}
```

I also have supplementary classes:

```
class BIOWrapper {
    let bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())
    init(data:NSData) {
        BIO_write(bio, data.bytes, Int32(data.length))
    }
    init() {}
    deinit {
        BIO_free(bio)
    }
}

class X509StoreWrapper {
    let store = X509_STORE_new()
    deinit {
        X509_STORE_free(store)
    }
    func addCert(x509:X509Wrapper) {
        X509_STORE_add_cert(store, x509.x509)
    }
}

class X509Wrapper {
    let x509 : UnsafeMutablePointer<X509>!
    init(data:NSData){
        let certBIO = BIOWrapper(data: data)
        x509 = d2i_X509_bio(certBIO.bio, nil)
    }
    deinit {
        X509_free(x509)
    }
}
```

All wrappers has init and deinit section. Other functions is from the build-in Crypto module... Frankly, I have no idea there the leak can be here. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allocating a `PKCS7` object but it seems you are never calling `PKCS7_free`. For example, you would need to call it right before `throw ReceiptError.receiptNotSigned`.

Notice in the stack trace on the right there are stack frames missing. You can view them by clicking on the icon the looks like a square with a line above and below that. That way you know exactly which function call is responsible for the allocation (and thus likely what it is that leaked).

Comment: I have added PKSC7_free call after `throw ReceiptError.receiptNotSigned`. Unfortunately has no any effect. Also i pressed the button you mentioned. Here is my stack trace - https://ibb.co/g43yR7 . I can't understand - It looks like CRYPTO_malloc   cause the problem? The CRYPTO_malloc on the top of my stack.

Comment: As I understood malloc allocate more memory than necessary?

Comment: If I do everything right the problem is still on the func 
 `extractPKCS7Container()` - screenshot: https://ibb.co/cR8UzS

Comment: The call to `PKCS7_free` needs to be inside the `guard` clause but _before_ `throw ReceiptError.receiptNotSigned` (code after a `throw` cannot be reached). The malloc simply isn't free'd. After your call to `extractPKCS7Container()`, you need to `PKCS7_free` your `container` variable.

Comment: I am sorry - type in it wrong. I insert it as you mentioned:  `guard PKCS7_verify(p7, nil, x509Store.store, nil, payload.bio, 0) == 1 else { PKCS7_free(p7) throw ... } ` I am trying to insert `PKCS7_free` on the right place in the main func...

Comment: Sir, You have made my day! Thank you a lot :)  Also I needed to add the free func on the main func:     `func validate() -> (Bool, String?) {
            let container = try extractPKCS7Container()
            let extractedReceipt = try parseContainer(container)
            ...
            PKCS7_free(container) // <- !very important!  ... }`